# not able to understand why this function return false if i change parameter value

Tags: javascript

I am learning java script [in here](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#12) and not able to understand this example, it returns false if i change ninja.yell(4) to any value for example ninja.yell(5) or 3.

```
var ninja = {
    yell: function(n) {
        return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n - 1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
    }
}; 
console.log(ninja.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "A single object isn't too bad, either.");
```

if I use function this way

```
var ninja = {
    yell: function(n) {
        return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n - 1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
    } 
}; 
console.log(ninja.yell(4));
```

it printing 'hiy' once and 'a' for four times like "hiyaaaa", I am really confused about this please help thanks.

Comment: Well, your console log checks if the returned string equals something, so it's either true or false, what do you expect?

Comment: is it some kind of loop going on here, this is what I dont understand

Comment: You could call it that, it's a recursive function call, so if `n` is more than zero, it calls the function again with `n-1` until it's zero.

Comment: Oookey here we go, now I understand thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function returns `hiy` followed by a number of `a`s equal to the number. You are comparing that to `hiyaaaa`.

If you change the number of `a`s then the comparison won't match.

Answer (score 0):

`ninja.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa"` is a comparison, it looks like the string "hiyaaaa" will change depending on the number you send to the method.

`ninja.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa"` literally means "Does ninja.yell(4) equal 'hiyaaaa'?"

If you change it to a 5, the return will actually have 5 a's, so it will not equal "hiyaaaa" so you get false